# response ajax and validation response with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make a register with ajax, validating data with laravel.
I realize sending, but not how to return the validation error and receive the error in the js code and display the error in a div.

I'm using version 5.2 of laravel. thanks the help :)

js:

```
function send(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({


        type: 'post',
        url: "{{route('NewUser')}}",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            cpassword: $('#cpassword').val(),
            _token: $('#new-user').attr('data-token')
        },
        success: function(errors){

            $('#Register').modal('hide');

        },
        error: function(errors) {


        }

    });

}
```

laravel controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
    public function NewUser(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request,[
                'name' => 'required|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|min:8|same:cpassword',
                'cpassword'=> 'required|min:8'
            ]);

            CreateNewUSer($request);

    }

    Protected function CreateNewUser(Request $request){

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reach your goal, I recommend you to use [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation)
First  of all create form request class

```
php artisan make:request UserRequest
```

Then add some rules in `rules` method of `UserRequest`

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|same:cpassword',
        'cpassword'=> 'required|min:8',
    ];
}
```

For simplicity all users can make this request(you should look over the docs, if you want check user permissions that way)

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

Further in your controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
    public function NewUser(UserRequest $request)
    {
            // laravel will validate request itself automatically and
            // will go on if validate pass or will return back with 
            // status code 422, input and errors otherwise

            CreateNewUSer($request);

    }

    Protected function CreateNewUser(Request $request){

    }
```

Finally you can catch errors in you js scripts using jQuery's ajax `.error()`

```
function send(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({


        type: 'post',
        url: "{{route('NewUser')}}",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            cpassword: $('#cpassword').val(),
            _token: $('#new-user').attr('data-token')
        },
        success: function(errors){

            $('#Register').modal('hide');

        },
        error: function(errors) {

            //handle errors here

        }

    });

}
```

**EDIT**
put this in view before js with ajax function

```
<script>
    var userAjax = "{{ route('NewUser') }}";
</script>
```

and your ajax js

```
 $.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: userAjax,
        dataType: 'json',
        // ...
```

Comment: hello, sorry for so many questions, it is not not want to read the documentation, but I do not speak English very well.

I implemented your advice, I used the code as you showed me, but nevertheless the code does not work, I always performs the function of error:

Comment: error: function(errors) {
            alert(console.log(errors));

        }                        show undefined

Comment: first of all use `error: function(errors) { console.log(errors); }`. What  do you see in console after request done?

Comment: you didn't set url properly. Is this code in dedicated js file? if so then you must define some variable with url route in your view and then use it in js.

Comment: and leave error messages, however, when no error messages do not realize the success parameter:... in de console show: undefined When validation it's ok

Answer (score 1):

Your validation errors will be returned as json so you can do something like

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    // success logic
  }),
  error: function(data){
    var errors = data.responseJSON;
    console.log(errors);
    // Render the errors with js ...
  }
});
```

so in error you will get all errors from validation.

Comment: errors are automatically sent with the code I have in the validation ??

Comment: when the validation it's OK, ejecute the error function, and when the validation it's fail, too ejecute error function. Never ejecute success function

Answer (score 0):

```
 $objValidator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|same:cpassword',
        'cpassword'=> 'required|min:8'
    ),array(
        'required'=>'Required',
        'email'=>'Invalid email',
        'unique' => 'exists'
    ));
    if($objValidator->fails())
    {
        return $objValidator->errors();
    }
```

Get array in your js code and than 
using $.each function you can show errors.
For exmple your have set, one div below your input box
html :

```
<div id="email_error" class="error" style="display:none">Email Already Exits.</div>

$.each(data, function (key,val) {
  $("#"+key+'_error').show();
});
```

Comment: you can be a little more specific with the part in js? thank you very much :)